# How to change button font when touch up outside?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

So I am trying to change the font of a button when it is pressed and then revert the font when the user touches up inside of another button. Changing the font when a user touches up inside currently works but I created an outlet from storyboard for a touchUpOutside action and tried to recycle the code and it is not working.

```
@IBAction func touchUpInside(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    sender.titleLabel?!.font = UIFont(name: "Futura-CondensedExtraBold", size: 25)
}
@IBAction func touchUpOutside(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    sender.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura-Medium", size: 22)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a non-nil value back from `UIFont(name: "Futura-Medium", size: 22)`? You might put an intermediate statement in there to make sure you're not just setting it to nil.

Comment: @Travis Griggs What do you mean by put an intermediate statement in there to test?

Comment: @TravisGriggs - wow this code actually is working but I was not understanding what "touch up outside" actually meant. This works when I press down, drag outside of button, and touch up. But do you know of anyway to revert font for button1 when pressing button2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revert font for button1 when pressing button2

If this is the answer you were looking for don't forget to except the answer.

```
//Button 1 as outlet.
@IBOutlet weak var button1Outlet: UIButton!

//Button 1 as touchUpInside.
@IBAction func button1(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    sender.titleLabel?!.font = UIFont(name: "Futura-CondensedExtraBold", size: 25)
}

//Button 2 as touchUpInside.
@IBAction func button2(_ sender: AnyObject) {

//Referenceing button 1 outlet.
    button1Outlet.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you have one button and when you touchUpInside the text font will change and when you touchUpOutside on the same button the text font will change to another font of revert back.

If this is the answer you were looking for don't forget to except the answer.

```
// The Button As An Outlet
@IBOutlet weak var theButton: UIButton!

// The Button using Touch Up Inside
@IBAction func theButtonInside(_ sender: AnyObject) {
     sender.titleLabel?!.font = UIFont(name: "Futura-CondensedExtraBold", size: 25)
}

// The Button using Touch Up Outside
@IBAction func theButtonOutside(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    //This is a reference to the button as an outlet.
    theButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura-Medium", size: 22)
}
```

Comment: No I had tried this previously it does not seem to work :(

Comment: wow this code actually is working but I was not understanding what "touch up outside" actually meant. This works when I press down, drag outside of button, and touch up. But do you know of anyway to revert font for button1 when pressing button2?